# How can i escape from endless loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create suffixer(name is what i make). 
URL exploder is below..

```
private function explode_url() {

    if (!empty($this->suffix) and empty($is)) {
                                             // look here  ------V
        $url = explode('/', rtrim($_GET['url'], $this->define_suffix())); 
    } else {
        $url = explode('/', trim($_GET['url'], '/'));
    }
    $str = '';
    foreach ($url as $key => $value) {
        if ($key >= 2) {
            $str = $str . '/' . $value;
        } else {
            $data[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $data[] = trim($str, '/');
    foreach ($data as $data) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $result[] = $data;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And here is the function that defines suffix.

```
private function define_suffix() {
        $count = count($this->explode_url()); // <------ look here
        $count = $count - 1;
        $keys = array('cnt', 'mtd', 'args');
        return $this->suffix[$keys[$count]];
    }
```

Actually functions work good but there is a problem. There is a endless loop. How can i escape this?

EDIT:
Output:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /var/www/cleanmvc/boot.php on line 85
```

**The functions call each other, which is causing the infinite loop. That's what I need help with.**

Answer (score -1):

The keyword to escape loops is `break`. If you're nested within loops, you can break multiple loops from the child loops by passing the optional parameter in: `break(2)` - breaks out of two levels.

Your infinite loop is here: `foreach ($data as $data) {`

Comment: Look "look here"s! this is not answer of my question.

Comment: What? I've clearly answered your question "How can i escape from endless loop?". Perhaps your question isn't asked properly, and/or the provided code is invalid. I provided you two answers, rather generous of me..

Comment: The functions call each other, which is causing the infinite loop. That's what I need help with.

Comment: Can you post what you're trying to accomplish?